# Understanding Mapreduce Code

Tags: java, mapreduce, hadoop2, movie

I am trying to practice Big Data Mapreduce by making Movie recommendation System . My code:

```
*imports



public class MRS {
    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context con)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();

            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line);

        while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
            String userId = token.nextToken();
            String movieId = token.nextToken();
            String ratings =token.nextToken();
            token.nextToken();
            con.write(new Text(userId), new Text(movieId + "," + ratings));
        }

    }
}

public static class Reduce extends
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> value,Context con ) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        int item_count=0;
        int item_sum =0;
        String result="[";
        for(Text t : value){
            String s = t.toString();
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
            while(token.hasMoreTokens()){
            token.nextToken();
            item_sum=item_sum+Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
            item_count++;
            }
            result=result+"("+s+"),";


        }
        result=result.substring(0, result.length()-1);
        result=result+"]";
        result=String.valueOf(item_count)+","+String.valueOf(item_sum)+","+result;

        con.write(key, new Text(result));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration con = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(con,"Movie Recommendation");

    job.setJarByClass(MRS.class);


    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);


    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);


    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);


    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));


    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

}

}
```

I am using the movielens dataset from [here](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/)

Of which input file is u.data

and my output after running this code should be like

userId    Item_count,Item_sum,[list of movie_Id with rating]

However, I am getting this

```
99  173,4
99  288,4
99  66,3
99  203,4
99  105,2
99  12,5
99  1,4
99  741,3
99  895,3
99  619,4
99  742,5
99  294,4
99  196,4
99  328,4
99  120,2
99  246,3
99  232,4
99  181,5
99  201,3
99  978,3
99  123,3
99  433,4
99  345,3
```

This should be the output of the Map class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made few adjustment to the code and it is giving me the exact expected result .
Here is my new code

imports*

```
public class MRS {
public static class Map extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context con)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        String[] s = line.split("\t");
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(line);

        while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
            IntWritable userId = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(token
                    .nextToken()));
            String movieId = token.nextToken();
            String ratings = token.nextToken();
            token.nextToken();
            con.write(userId, new Text(movieId + "," + ratings));
        }

    }
}

public static class Reduce extends
        Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> value, Context con)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int item_count = 0;
        int item_sum = 0;
        String result = "";
        for (Text t : value) {
            String s = t.toString();
            StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");

            result = result + "[" + s + "],";

        }
        result = result.substring(1, result.length() - 2);

        System.out.println(result);
        con.write(key, new Text(result));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration con = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(con, "Movie Recommendation");

    job.setJarByClass(MRS.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

}

}
```

what I change is
Driver code

```
job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
```

Mapper code

```
 Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text>
```

Reducer code

```
 public static class Reduce extends
    Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, Text> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> value,Context con ) throws 
 IOException, InterruptedException{
```

I think the problem was that the outputkey and outputvalue data is matching the mapper class thats why it is printing mapper and not even executng reducer

Correct me if I am wrong.